# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path.No Submodule present

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting this error while deploying `NugetGallery` git project on azure website.

But when I try following command and check I have `not found any submodule`

```
C:\NuGetGallery-master [master]> git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
160000 e35ece8c542e50bcfd71d0c5ed528d1b8206389f 0       mydemonugetgallery
```

> what should be cause ?

deployment failed error :
Updating submodules.

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'mydemonugetgallery'

D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe submodule update --init --recursive
```

which entry i should have to insert in `.gitmodules`

```
[submodule "mydemonugetgallery"]
    path = ext/Slab
    url = https://git01.codeplex.com/slab
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear: There doesn't appear to be a mapping for that submodule in your `.gitmodules` file. Do you have a `.gitmodules` file in the root of your repository? If so, does it contain an entry for `mydemonugetgallery`?

Comment: it does not contain an entry..which entry i should have to insert?

Comment: Based on your edit, it looks like there *is* an entry for `mydemonugetgallery`. Did you add that, or was it already there? Do you want this submodule to be located in `mydemonugetgallery` or in `ext/Slab`?

Comment: I have added that to give a try but it is not working :\

Comment: basically I'm updating git hub Nugetgallery in azure websites 
I tried using this youtube video but I;m getting these errors https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72SAHWUHnzA

Comment: So I have downloaded code from github in C:\MYGallery and after creating azure websites and executing all commands it have created new folder mydemonugetgallery inside C:\MYGallery

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Is `mydemonugetgallery` supposed to be your main project? It looks like ``C:\MYGallery\`` is also a repository. Should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note more recent versions of the NuGetGallery project do not have support for running on Azure App Service Web App.